# How to listen to real-time updates on android

Tags: getstream-io

I reviewed documentation about receive updates of getstream but only way is using javascript client. https://getstream.io/docs/#realtime

Is there any way for implementing real-time update on android?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of Android libraries for websockets, but several considerations to keep in mind if you choose to develop this in your app:

- keeping a data connection open to Stream will use a lot more data on mobile plans
- open data connections will keep wifi/cell radios engaged, draining more battery
- each websocket connection can only watch a single feed -- if you have multiple feeds to watch then you'll use up more connections per mobile client
- you have a limited number of websocket connections for real-time notifications (free plans only get 250 connections, for example)

We typically recommend having a back-end system that watches all of these feeds periodically, and doing a push notification to the mobile client instead of using the websocket connections. This gives you a lot more flexibility on how often to watch for changes and minimize your users' data and battery consumption.

Our SDKs, which would be part of your back-end application anyway, would generate the token for the client. You can check our SDKs' README files for examples, such as https://github.com/GetStream/stream-python (search for `read-only token` on the page).

Comment: If i do want to connect to webhooks from my client side, is there any way or guides to do that, I couldn't find anything related to connecting using webhook, I only found realtime subscription implemented in stream-js using Faye?